# How to retrieve dual-boot option after Windows reinstall?

Tags: dual-boot, slackware

Initially I had set up Slackware 13.37 and Windows 7 Home Premium dual boot. After upgrading to Windows 7 Ultimate, the dual-boot window does not show anymore so I cannot choose to boot Slackware.

Is there a way to fix this without deleting the Slackware partition and reinstalling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reinstall GRUB, you can do this from a chroot. Boot into a live CD, chroot into your Linux system and issue `grub-install`.

Something like the following should work (assuming `/dev/sda2` is `/` and `/dev/sda1` is `/boot`, and you want to install to the MBR on `/dev/sda`):

```
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
mount -t proc none /mnt/proc
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
grub-install /dev/sda
```

Or if you're using LILO, use `lilo /dev/sda` instead.

Comment: IIRC Slackware still uses LILO, so the way forward would be to call `/sbin/lilo` instead of grub-install.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Not a Slackware user, so I wouldn't know. Updated with alternative, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't delete the linux partition.

The easiest way is setup `grub4dos` in your Windows 7 installation, or use an external media, do the chroot stuff, and restore the grub from your slack installation.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get back your Linux distros is by simply using the Fedora DVD that you installed with previously.

It hardly takes 1 minute to reconfigure your bootloader.

Then you get your dual boot options with default selected as Linux.